# Vapor UserAuthenticator never used, req.auth.require(User.self) always fails

Tags: swift, authentication, authorization, vapor

I have created a `login` endpoint:

```
    try LoginUserDTO.validate(content: request)
    let loginUserDTO = try request.content.decode(LoginUserDTO.self)
    let userService = UserService(database: request.db)

    let user = try await userService.get(by: loginUserDTO.email)

    if (try user.verify(password: loginUserDTO.password)) == false {
        throw Abort(.unauthorized)
    }

    let userToken = UserToken(accessToken: generateToken(),
              refreshToken: generateToken(),
              accessTokenExpirationDate: generateAccessTokenExpirationDate(),
              refreshTokenExpirationDate: generateRefreshTokenExpirationDate(),
              user: user)

    try await userToken.create(on: request.db)

    request.auth.login(user)

    return ClientTokenReponse(accessToken: userToken.accessToken,
                              refreshToken: userToken.refreshToken,
                              accessTokenExpirationDate: userToken.accessTokenExpirationDate,
                              refreshTokenExpirationDate: userToken.refreshTokenExpirationDate)
```

Check user's credentials, create and return the token. Now I want to test if my `UserAuthenticator` works:

```
struct UserAuthenticator: AsyncBearerAuthenticator {

func authenticate(bearer: BearerAuthorization, for request: Request) async throws {
    typealias User = App.User

    let loginUser = try request.query.decode(LoginUserDTO.self)

    guard let user = try await User.query(on: request.db)
        .filter(\.$email == loginUser.email)
        .first(),
    let userId = user.id else {
        throw Abort(.notFound)
    }

    guard let userToken = try await UserToken.query(on: request.db)
        .filter(\.$user.$id == userId)
        .first() else {
        throw Abort(.notFound)
    }

    // TODO: Add additional check if accessToken is not expired yet!

    if bearer.token == userToken.accessToken {
        request.auth.login(loginUser.toUser())
    }
}
}
```

So I added:

```
    let protected = app.grouped([User.authenticator()])
protected.post("me") { request async throws -> String in
    let user = try? request.auth.require(User.self)

    if user != nil {
        return "yes"
    } else {
        return "no"
    }
}
```

The User is obviously always nil. It seems like the code inside my `UserAuthenticator` is never even executed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, made a couple of changes and suddenly it worked:

Changed my `authenticate()` method because it was expecting the email and password being passed in the request (which is nonsense since the bearer is sent in the headers :) ).

```
    func authenticate(bearer: BearerAuthorization, for request: Request) async throws {
    guard let userToken = try await UserToken.query(on: request.db)
        .join(User.self, on: \UserToken.$user.$id == \User.$id)
        .filter(\.$accessToken == bearer.token)
        .first()
    else {
        throw Abort(.unauthorized)
    }

    let user = try userToken.joined(User.self)

    // TODO: Add check if accessToken is not expired yet!

    if bearer.token == userToken.accessToken {
        request.auth.login(User(email: user.email, passwordHash: user.passwordHash))
    }
}
```

Another this is how I use the `UserAuthenticator` in the `routes` file:

using:

```
let protected = app.grouped(UserAuthenticator())
```

instead of:

```
let protected = app.grouped([User.authenticator()])
```

worked!